# Changing style tag with javascript [Slider]

Tags: javascript, html, css

www.imgur.com/8bq1X.png

I would like it to remove the style display:none from the yellow highlighted bit when the blue highlighted bit is selected.

How would I edit this code to do that?

```
(function(IIS) {
"use strict";

IIS.Slider.prototype.addCaptions = function() {
    IIS._addClass(this._attributes.container, 'iis-has-captions');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this._attributes.slides, function(slide, i){
        var caption = document.createElement('div');
        IIS._addClass(caption, 'iis-caption');

        var captionContent = '';
        if(slide.getAttribute('title')){
            captionContent += '<div class="iis-caption-title">'+ slide.getAttribute('title') +'</div>';
        }
        if(slide.getAttribute('data-caption')){
            var dataCaption = slide.getAttribute('data-caption');
            if(dataCaption.substring(0,1) == '#' || dataCaption.substring(0,1) == '.'){
                var external = document.querySelector(dataCaption);
                if(external){
                    captionContent += '<div class="iis-caption-content">'+ external.innerHTML +'</div>';
                }
            } else {
                captionContent += '<div class="iis-caption-content">'+ slide.getAttribute('data-caption') +'</div>';
            }
        } else {
            if(slide.innerHTML){
                captionContent += '<div class="iis-caption-content">'+ slide.innerHTML +'</div>';
            }
        }

        slide.innerHTML = '';
        if(captionContent){
            caption.innerHTML = captionContent;
            slide.appendChild(caption);
        }
    }.bind(this));
};

return IIS;

})(IdealImageSlider);
```